# Should i just use 1 database?

Tags: winforms, database-design, azure, multi-tenant

Hi i am building a window apps retailer pos but was wondering what is the best method to design the database. Should i just use 1 database to store all my clients data?
Meaning to say if i have 100 clients from different businesses using my App, all of their data will be stored in 1 database. 
e.g. i will store 1 company column in the user table to indicate which company does the customer or transaction belongs to.
My current practice is i create new database for each business and put it installed into their local machine. (Got to manually install sqlserver + sqlexpress).

Do u think it is more easier for me to design in this way? and i can just put the database online to sql server. Will i be getting any latency ? how bad will it be? I heard Window Azure able to handle this well. In my case i think the speed and data size per business is not really a concern.

Could you advice?

Comment: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/how-design-multiclient-databases/

Comment: Sound like this has been a great topic discussed before. thanks

Comment: SO has a tag for those kinds of questions: [multi-tenant].

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look at other alternatives within Azure for storing data, specifically Azure Storage Tables and Blobs.
Utilizing all of the Azure Storage Options with SQL Azure will allow you to choose different data tiers depending on your application's needs and your desired cost structure.  Running everything inside of SQL Azure will cost you more in the long run, but it makes a good place to tie together federated data for relational reporting, whereas you can store each tenant's data inside of Azure Tables, using PartitionKeys which keep each client's data separated from the others.